# Reviewing the badges page often references questions that have been removed due to moderation. Is this by design or a an unintended consequence?

Tags: discussion, bug

Reviewing the "evidence" of the Reversal badge (https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) often links to questions that have been

> removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation

Is this expected behavior, or an unintended consequence of removing the question? Examples include [No typing in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522346/no-typing-in-input-field/11522357#11522357) and [Is jQuery faster than javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324087/is-jquery-faster-than-javascript/2324098#2324098). The badge system seems broken if we can't review the evidence of the award — plus it can be entertaining in the case of the Reversal badge.

Comment: It's an *intended* consequence of removing the question.  Some badges aren't reversed due to post deletions; they're just debited against future badge awards.

Comment: What do you mean by "expected behavior"? That you can't actually see the deleted question? That's as expected

Comment: @Bart yes, that is what I meant. I thought it may have been unintentional to delete the proof for the badge award.

Comment: Deleted questions are, well, deleted and besides the OP visible only to users with a reputation of 10k or higher.

Comment: [Note that disassociations don't remove the badge either.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1615209/phasair)

Comment: If a question has been used to award the Reversal badge, shouldn't that question be protected from deletion so it can be referenced on the badge page?

Comment: @Mysticial I agree, but I can still click on his Famous Question badge and see [which question he asked](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question?userid=1615209)  to earn the badge (the evidence of the badge).

Comment: You're right about those questions being a good source of entertainment. The comment thread on [Fastest way in C# to iterate through ALL Guids Possible (10K only link)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10029651/119477) is awesome. I guess you have found good motivation for earning 10K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal.

1. The question usually needs to be bad to be downvoted.
2. The Reversal badge requires that the question be downvoted.
3. Bad questions tend to get deleted.

---

Badges aren't removed if the question is deleted. The ultimate result is that a large number of Reversal badges are rewarded on questions that are eventually deleted.